# How to expose .env variables to the client in NUXT 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a nuxt config file that tries to expose all my .env variables to the client.
Some varibles are exposed and I can access them(i'm accessing using useRuntimeConfi()), and some just return "undefined" whenever i try to access them

I do not know what the cause might be, but here's my code to look at:

nuct.config.ts:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    /*
     ** Runtime Variables
     */
    runtimeConfig: {
      apiVersion: process.env.API_VERSION || 'alpha',
      cmsUrl: process.env.CMS_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
      cmsToken: process.env.CMS_TOKEN || 'token',
      public: {
        baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000',
        auth0Domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        auth0ClientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI || 'http://localhost:3000/',
        stagingUri: process.env.STAGING_URI,
        localDevUri: process.env.LOCAL_DEV_URI,
        cmsUrl: process.env.CMS_URL || 'http://localhost:1337',
      }
    },
});
```

my auth.js file:

```
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
import { useRuntimeConfig } from 'nuxt/app';

//the below console.log returns undefined
console.log(useRuntimeConfig().stagingUri, useRuntimeConfig().redirectUri;

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const auth0 = createAuth0({
    domain: useRuntimeConfig().auth0Domain,
    clientId: useRuntimeConfig().auth0ClientID,
    authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: useRuntimeConfig().redirectUri || useRuntimeConfig().stagingUri,
    },
    logoutParams: {
      returnTo: useRuntimeConfig().redirectUri || useRuntimeConfig().localDevUri,
    },
    useRefreshTokens: true,
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage'
  });

  if (process.client) {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(auth0);
  }

  addRouteMiddleware('auth', () => {
    if (process.client) {
      auth0.checkSession();
      if (!auth0.isAuthenticated.value) {
        auth0.loginWithRedirect({
          appState: {
            target: useRoute().path,
          },
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

As you can see from the file, the redirectUri property is defined but the stagingUri and localDevUri is undefined. Why is that??

Answer (score 4):

Got similar issue when I had new data inside `.env & runtimeConfig()`. I got undefined for my new datas.
My nuxt version was 3.2.3. I upgrade for the last nuxt version and it work now.

Inside .env : `NUXT_PUBLIC_stagingUri=something`

```
runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      stagingUri: process.env.stagingUri
    },
  },
```

And use `useRuntimeConfig().public.stagingUri` to access indeed

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use env vars in nuxt3 you need to set the VITE_VARIABLE in .env file and use import.meta.env

example to use

.env

```
VITE_BASE_URL=https://apiurl.com
```

vue file

```
<script setup>
const baseUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL}`
console.log(baseUrl)
</script>
```

i think that helped you.

that way you can access the env vars outside nuxt scope, with another plugins ex. pinia

Answer (score 0):

Include the `public` key in your `useRuntimeConfig()`

```js
const auth0 = createAuth0({
    domain: useRuntimeConfig().public.auth0Domain, // Add the .public
    clientId: useRuntimeConfig().public.auth0ClientID, // Add .public
    authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: useRuntimeConfig().public.redirectUri || useRuntimeConfig().public.stagingUri, // Add .public
    },
    logoutParams: {
      returnTo: useRuntimeConfig().public.redirectUri || useRuntimeConfig().public.localDevUri, // Add .public
    },
    useRefreshTokens: true,
    cacheLocation: 'localstorage'
  });
```

Accessing the `useRuntimeConfig().public` will display all the available public config variables.

Answer (score 0):

As your question, you have to move .env file's variables into the nuxt.config.js inside **env**  object.
For an example,

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  env: {
    MY_VARIABLE: config.MY_VARIABLE,
  },
}
```

Then you can access those variables inside any components or classes.

```
computed: {
    myVeriable {
      return process.env.MY_VARIABLE
    },
  },
```